# I don't know how to use statement driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping, splinter

I tried writing

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, value='10').click()
```

and I get the following command line feedback:

```
    uname = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, '10').click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 680, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n
 (Session info: chrome=28.0.1500.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=
Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

Other permutations of my statement produce somewhat similar looking feedback.  (The '10' I'm writing is a link to another page, e.g., "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...")

I'm trying to go to page 10.  I don't know how.  Even getting to line 2 would be a start I'd be contented with.

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**

If I write `driver.find_element_by_link_text('10').click()` then I get this feedback:

```
    uname = driver.find_element_by_link_text('10').click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 246, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 680, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n
 (Session info: chrome=28.0.1500.95)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=
Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

**UPDATE II:**  This is the code I have to work from:

```
import time
import win32ui
import win32api
import win32con
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from ctypes import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://[site]');
```

Comment: The exception you're seeing is due to `WebDriver` being unable to find any `<a>` elements with the `text` "10". Could you provide the corresponding `HTML` in your question so we can further assist? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark.  I want to click this:  <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$FormContent$gvResults','Page$4')">4</a>.  I don't know how.

Comment: I've appended the code I work from, above in a post update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('10').click()
```

Comment: Richard, thank you for replying.  I've updated my post above after trying your kind suggestion.

Comment: Richard, thanks for this.  It works if I allow enough time for the screen to change to the one that contains this numerical sequence (I put a sleep() instruction in front of it).  Being so new to this, I didn't know how asynchronous this library is.  Thanks again.